# Postgres SQL dropping table drops all dependent views?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In postgres when I drop a table it is dropping all views that depend upon it. Is there a way to persist the views so that they dont get dropped

Note: the table will be regenerated on daily basis with new data.

Comment: What would a view do if its backing tables are gone?

Comment: Do you want to turn the view into a table?

Comment: If the table is not there(_after deleting table_) then what will be the purpose a view that made with deleted table? To get a an exception like this `ERROR:  relation "deleted_table_name" does not exist`,huh ?. I guess you don't know what actually a view is,isn't it?. **a view is a _virtual table_ based on the result-set of an SQL statement**. **The fields in a view are fields from one or more real tables in the database**

Comment: the table would be recreated.

Answer (score 2):

From [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-droptable.html)

> DROP TABLE always removes any indexes, rules, triggers, and constraints that exist for the target table. However, to drop a table that is referenced by a view or a foreign-key constraint of another table, CASCADE must be specified. (**CASCADE will remove a dependent view entirely, but in the foreign-key case it will only remove the foreign-key constraint**, not the other table entirely.)

Answer (score 0):

Try TRUNCATE TABLE / CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS instead of DROP.

Comment: That's not a substitute for `DROP TABLE`, is it?

Comment: It is if you want to keep views defined

Comment: OP wants to drop the view so that he can redefine it in some other way. How can `TRUNCATE` help with that?